# Code for open camera on Android does not work in Samsung S3

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I have the following code to open the camera app from my app in Android. It works fine on Samsung Galaxy Nexus, but it crashes on Samsung Galaxy S3, unfortunately I don't have the latter device in order to debug the problem, any suggestions?

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + this.getString(R.string.kda_images));
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + this.getString(R.string.kda_images) + File.separator + "Image-" + dir.listFiles().length + ".jpg");
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));//The selected image is created in the specified location: file
    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));//Refreshes the directory to show the new image
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_NEW_IMAGE);
```

Comment: Have you tried just launching the camera app from its launcher? Sometimes the error is in the camera app itself, as suggested by a lot of S3 user here http://forums.androidcentral.com/t-galaxy-s-iii/257997-galaxy-s3-camera-crashing.html

Comment: the camera works perfectly fine

Comment: btw - for remote debug log collection, I found a simple app called SendLog on the store. Maybe its not the best, but it worked for me. Otherwise some of the online crash collection services like Crittercism.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use bellow code because my end it work properly in galaxy s3 device.

Intent action = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE")
action.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString());
                                    startActivityForResult(action,TAKE_PICTURE_FROM_CAMERA);